# Draw a vertical line on a wpf RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I have a custom RichTextBox class that I want to draw a vertical line on.  (The idea is that it will show a "Char Limit".)

I have tried overriding OnRender, but that did not draw anything.

I have read of using Adorners, but they update how text looks.  (I just want to draw a line, nothing related to the text.)

**Is there a way to just draw a vertical line from the top to the bottom?**

Comment: Possible typo: Horizontal or vertical? :)

Comment: No probs. Also, possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158291/how-to-draw-border-around-a-word-in-richtextbox

Comment: Presumably it needs to cope with the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @weston - That would be best (if possible).  But at this point I would settle for anything that could draw on the RichTextBox that is not attached to text.

Comment: Why not just limit the width?

Comment: @Blam-I am working on a way to limit the width of text (and still have the control larger than that).  But I want to give them a visual indicator where the limit is.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way:

```
<Grid x:Name="Container" Height="100">
    <RichTextBox/>
    <Line Stroke="Aqua" X1="160" X2="160" Y1="0" Y2="{Binding Path=Height,ElementName=Container}" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
</Grid>
```

`IsHitTestVisible="False"` is just incase they click right on the line, don't want that to eat the mouse click.