# RTF - Box Around A Word?

Tags: c#, border, rtf, text-formatting

In **RTF** is it possible to make a word appear with a box around it ? I'm not sure if `Table` is the right choice because I don't want to get alignment problems.

- line height must be the same as normal text
- color for the border
- should behave as normal text

*(not relevant but I'm working in C# with RTF)*

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158291/how-to-draw-border-around-a-word-in-richtextbox

Comment: @ToastyMallows It is a very different path. I'm looking for an RTF solution. I don't draw, I'm manipulating strings of RTF code.

Answer (score 1):

You can put borders around both text and paragraphs in RTF as the following simple example RTF shows

```
{\rtf1
{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;\red0\green255\blue0;}
\pard\plain
\brdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20\brdrcf2 
\brdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\brsp80 
\brdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20 
\brdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\brsp80  
Hello 
{\chbrdr\brdrs\brdrw10\brsp20\brdrcf3 World}
}
```

To highlight a single word start with the `\chrbrdr` keyword (this applies borders to all sides, you can't have different borders on each side for text, but you can for paragraphs). The border style is then modified by the following keywords

`\brdrs` - sets a single thickness border. There are lots of alternative border styles like double, dash, dot-dash, etc. See the [RTF specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10725#)

`\brdrw10` - sets the width of the border, in twips (a twip is a twentieth of a point). Here to 10 twips

`\brsp20` - sets the separation of the border from the text, again in twips - here set to 20 twips. Note that setting this value too high may affect your line spacing.

`brdrcf3` - sets the colour of the border, by index into the colour table.

As you can see in the example you end the border highlighting of a word by scoping the highlight with a `{}` pair.

The example RTF also shows a paragraph border, where it is possible to set the style for the top, bottom, left and right borders separately.

It's possible that some RTF viewers may not implement the display of text and/or paragraph borders. The sample above displays correctly for me in Microsoft Word (2013), but I actually can't seem to find a way to edit the word border inside the Word UI. Editing the paragraph border is available in the Paragraph Formatting dialog.

Comment: I can't get you sample to work. I'm using RichTextBox from C#. It can display Tables. And I'm not sure if it's the same as your sample does. I have no use for tables but I want some text surrounded with a border.

Comment: Ah, ok, I didn't realize you were using RichTextBox - thought you were creating RTF using C# to display in Word or similar (sample looks correct in Word). Looks like the RichTextBox doesn't support the display of paragraph or text borders, which is the way this is supposed to be done in RTF. I can't think of another way to do this in RTF right now - tables will disturb the flow of the document (they are always alone on a line).

Some ideas : 

* Change from RTF to HTML - should be easy to put border on <span>
* Try an alternate RTF control (various companies sell for $$$)

Comment: Can you provide a little screenshot of what you see in word ? Or give a hint how I can make word "interpret" RTF code ?

Comment: Not sure how to put a screen shot here, but to get the RTF into word, do the following : Open notepad, paste RTF code copied from above into notepad, File->SaveAs, name file 'test.rtf'. Check file is really 'test.rtf', not 'test.rtf.txt' and rename if necessary. Open 'test.rtf' in Word.